# Use self-compiled OpenSSL to compile bitcoin on fedora 21

Tags: c++, bitcoin, fedora-21

Right now I can build the `bitcoin-qt` and execute it but it immediately exits with this Error:

> OpenSSL appears to lack support for elliptic curve cryptography. For
>   more information, visit
>   https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OpenSSL_and_EC_Libraries

The website only links to some outdated rpms for fedora 19 but it is also mentioned one could "compile [their] own OpenSSL and use this".

I can download and compile OpenSSL but I never managed to **tell bitcoin where OpenSSL is located.**

What I tried yesterday: (instructions from https://opennet.hackpad.com/ep/pad/static/HqezreF8xmh )

- install dependecies
- export OPENSSL_PREFIX=/tmp/folder1
- Download and unzip openssl-1.0.2a source code
- CC='cc -fPIC' ./config --prefix=$OPENSSL_PREFIX
- make all install_sw
- Download and unzip bitcoin source code
- ./autogen.sh
- ./configure SSL_CFLAGS=' ' SSL_LIBS="$OPENSSL_PREFIX/lib/libssl.a $OPENSSL_PREFIX/lib/libcrypto.a -ldl" CRYPTO_CFLAGS=' ' CRYPTO_LIBS=' '
- make

But this failed with

```
libbitcoin_util.a(libbitcoin_util_a-random.o): In function `RandAddSeed()':
/tmp/test2/bitcoin/src/random.cpp:42: undefined reference to `RAND_add'
```

Comment: Is OPENSSL_PREFIX really blank or did you just omit its value?  It's supposed to point to a write-accessible directory.

Comment: I used some folders in /tmp/ to do all the stuff. (Fixed this in the OP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind overwriting your current version of openssl, try to do an "update" to openssl:

```
./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared
make
make test
make install
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22952749/2084795